# Gridsome Could not generate HTML for

Tags: gridsome

I am using Gridsome witha Strapi API.  I'm using the api.createPates method in gridsome.server.js to get data from the api and generate pages based on that data. The below code seems to be causing a problem:

```
    let localizedOverviewData = {}
    if(overviewData.series.localizations?.data) {
      overviewData.series.localizations.data.forEach(async locale => {
        localizedOverviewData = await axios.get(process.env.API_ENDPOINT_BASE + 'series-info' + query + '&locale=' + locale.attributes.locale, config)
        localizedOverviewData = {
          series: localizedOverviewData.data.data.attributes,
          events: upcomingEvents,
          pastEvents: pastEvents
        }
        createPage({
          path: '/' + locale.attributes.locale,
          component: './src/templates/Overview.vue',
          context: localizedOverviewData
        })
        createPage({
          path: '/' + locale.attributes.locale + '/past-summits',
          component: './src/templates/PastSummits.vue',
          context: localizedOverviewData
        })
      })
    }
```

When I build the project I get

```
Could not generate HTML for "/zh/past-summits/":
Error: Could not resolve /zh/past-summits.
    at assets/js/app.0b54624b.js:4308:23
    at /Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2836:23
    at /Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2266:21
    at /Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2404:7
    at step (/Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2003:7)
    at step (/Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2010:9)
    at runQueue (/Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2014:3)
    at /Users/VertizonticalStudios/Websites/discovery-website-generator/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js:2399:5
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?  If I comment out the two createPage functions it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer.  The issue was using 'async' on my for each loop.  Apparently that doesn't work.  Switching it to a for loop fixed it.